# Why can't I detect that the tuple is empty?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tuples

I am using the where function in numpy to look for a one letter string in an array of strings. 
For example:
I will look for `'U'` in `['B' 'U' 'A' 'M' 'R' 'O']` and get the index of `'U'`.

```
letter = 'U'
row = ['B', 'U', 'A', 'M', 'R', 'O']
letter_found = np.where(row == letter)
```

However when I am looking for a letter that isn't present in the array of strings I get an empty tuple that looks like this:

```
(array([], dtype=int64),)
```

I need to be able to detect when it does not find the letter I am looking for in the array.

I've tried the following:

```
if not letter_found:
    print 'not found'
```

But this does not work. How can I detect that the `tuple` returned from the where function in `numpy` is empty? Is it because one of my variables is possibly the wrong type? I am new at `python` and programming in general.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The nomeclature:

```
if some_iterable:
    #only if non-empty
```

only works when something is empty. In your case, the tuple isn't actually empty. The thing the tuple contains is empty. So you might want to do the following:

```
if any(map(len, my_tuple)):
    #passes if any of the contained items are not empty
```

as `len` on an empty iterable will yield `0` and thus will be converted to `False`.

Comment: no need for `map(len...` here, just `any(my_tuple)` should do the trick!

Comment: I'm not sure whether just `any(my_tuple)` will work for this specific case, since the elements of the tuple are `numpy` arrays and cannot be used directly in boolean contexts.

Answer (score 4):

Your test is failing because `letter_found` is actually a tuple containing one element, so it's not empty. `numpy.where` returns a tuple of index values, one for each dimension in the array that you're testing. Typically when using this for searching in one-dimensional arrays, I use Python's tuple unpacking to avoid just this sort of situation:

```
letter = 'U'
row = ['B', 'U', 'A', 'M', 'R', 'O']
letter_found, = np.where(row == letter)
```

Note the comma after `letter_found`. This will unpack the result from `numpy.where` and assign `letter_found` to be the first element of that tuple.

Note also that `letter_found` will now refer to a numpy array, which cannot be used in a boolean context. You'll have to do something like:

```
if len(letter_found) == 0:
    print('not found!')
```